# MvvmCross remove back stack windows app

Tags: windows, stack, mvvmcross, back

How can I clear the back stack in windows apps (not windows phone)?
I am using MvvmCross v3. Where is the most correct place to put it?

I have read this post http://edsnider.net/2014/04/07/clearing-windows-phone-nav-back-stack-in-mvvmcross/ where he is using ***CustomWP8ViewPresenter***

```
    public override void ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint)
    {
        if (hint is ClearNavBackStackHint)
        {
            while (RootFrame.BackStack.Any())
            {
                RootFrame.RemoveBackEntry();
            }
        }

        base.ChangePresentation(hint);
    }
```

My problem is that in windows app I do not have *RootFrame.RemoveBackEntry()* as an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/ViewModel--to-ViewModel-navigation#how-do-i-remove-views-and-viewmodels-from-the-back-stack modified to use WinRT type navigation state mechanisms like http://www.allaboutdave.me/post/2013/11/22/windows-81-clear-back-stack.aspx,

Comment: @Stuart thank you for the links, but non of them solves my problem. Let me explain. I have _IMvxAppStart_ which is **LoginViewModel** and after the login is successful I want to navigate to **MainPageViewModel** and delete previous history.

Comment: @Stuart, my point is _IMvxWindowsFrame_  (from MvxWindowsViewPresenter) instance does not have **Frame.BackStack...**.

Comment: And that's the same point as http://www.allaboutdave.me/post/2013/11/22/windows-81-clear-back-stack.aspx ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `IMvxWindowsFrame` mentioned in comments is just simple wrapper around `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame` instance. You can get this wrapped instance by calling:

```
_rootFrame = (Frame) rootFrame.UnderlyingControl;
```

Then you can delete your backstack like this:

```
if (hint is ClearNavBackStackHint)
{
    if (_rootFrame.BackStackDepth > 0)
    {
        _rootFrame.BackStack.RemoveAt(_rootFrame.BackStack.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I needed the frame, but didn't know it was its **UnderlyingControl** :)