# How to respond to toast notifcations in MVVMCross UWP app

Tags: uwp, mvvmcross

I have a windows UWP app written with MVVPCross.  The application method OnActivated is called when the user clicks on a Toast Notifcation message.

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle toast activation
    if (e is ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs)
    {
        var toastActivationArgs = e as ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs;

    }
}
```

When I get this event it want to:

- clear the navigation history
- Renavigate to the home page with information passed to it from the toast event
- The home page will then reload itself and set the initial selection based on info passed to it

I'm looking for guidance how I can force a navigation via the mvvmcross framework.  I know how to navigate from one view model to another but in this case, I'm not in the context of a view or a view model - i'm in the context of the Windows.UI.Xaml.Application object.

thanks,
michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only thing you need is instance of current frame

```
        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.ToastNotification)
        {
            try
            {
                if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
                {
                    var fr = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
                    var toastActivationArgs = args as ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs;
                    fr.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), toastActivationArgs);
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

In your MainPage OnNavigatedTo action you can get Navigation parameters and do whatever you want .

Comment: I think with MVVMCross it's different from this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with `MVVMCross` but a quick google search brought me up to speed. So here is the thing:

1. To clear the navigation back stack (navigation history) refer [this blog](http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20140721-RemovingAViewFromBackStackInMvvmCrossForWindowsStoreApps.html). It defines a clean way to do so. Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30513811/3766231) on stack does provide insights to a more application point of view.
2. To navigate from to the home page you'll need to get the current instance of the Frame which is actually hosting your app. so a quick `Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;` should get you done. More about this in the documentation [here](https://mvvmcross.com/v4.3/docs/a-windows-universal-app-platform-project). Do a quick search for "Current" on the web site and you'll find the code
3. To refresh the page, you can refer [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857543/mvvmcross-viewmodel-caching-and-re-initializing) on stack